# xcode: how to turn off the treat warning as error only for archiving

Tags: ios, xcode

On our app, we want to turn on "treat warning as error" flag. However, we have a warning that we cannot fix it or ignore it using pragma for now. Is there any way to change the actions for the archiving and turn the "treat warning as error" flag off for it only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Build Settings and find the "Treat Warnings as Errors" setting. Open the little triangle to the left of the setting and you should see a value for Debug and a value for Release.

Change the Release value to No.